# Finding next 30 days from today

Tags: c#, json, linq, windows-phone-7

For the following json:

```
{
  "id": "100001","Emp": {"data": [
     {
        "birthday": "08/14/1987", 
        "id": "52442"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "52554"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "54281"
      }, 
      {
        "birthday": "04/08/1986", 
        "id": "54353"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "58667"
      }, 
      {
        "birthday": "12/20", 
        "id": "61435"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "62794"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "64577"
      }, 
      {
        "birthday": "08/12", 
        "id": "65151"
      }, 
      {
        "birthday": "11/15/1988", 
        "id": "66075"
      },
      {
        "birthday": "08/02", 
        "id": "68282"
      }, 
      {
        "birthday": "05/01", 
        "id": "70120"
      }, 
      {
        "birthday": "12/24/1989", 
        "id": "74611"
      }, 
      {
        "birthday": "06/18", 
        "id": "10293"
      }
  ], 
 }
}
```

Some `Emp` objects don't have a `birthday` property and some birthdays doesn't have a year defined.

Now my task is to get the next 30 Emp objects with birthdays starting from today

My code is Like this

```
var response = e.Result;
var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
jsonData.emp.data = jsonData.friends.data.Where(BdayItems => (BdayItems.birthday != null && DateTime.Parse(BdayItems.birthday)<= DateTime.Today.AddDays(30))).OrderBy(BdayItems => BdayItems.birthday).ToList();
```

I also tried to remove year by using `.AddYear(-1)` in the LINQ query.

But I'm not getting next 30 day, I am getting all `Emp` birthday list, but I need only need the next 30 days from today

Comment: `DateTime.Parse(BdayItems.birthday)<= DateTime.Today.AddDays(30)` ?? If the birthday is "08/14/1987", it will always be less than today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to convert the birthdays to the current year first. You could do this by adding the difference between the birthdate year and the current year. Or if you care about a specific way of handling leap years, just use the DateTime constructor and your own leap year handling algorithm.

Also, as another answer addressed, you should ensure the birthday (in the current year) is at or after the current date.

As requested, here's an example of one way to do this. This uses the leap year handling of AddYears.

```
jsonData.friends.data.Where(BdayItems =>
{
    if (BdayItems.birthday != null)
    {
        var originalBirthday = DateTime.Parse(BdayItems.birthday);
        var today = DateTime.Today; //Storing this prevents a race condition.
        var birthdayThisYear = originalBirthday.AddYears(today.Years - originalBirthday.Years);
        var thirtyDaysFromNow = today.AddDays(30);

        return birthdayThisYear >= today && birthdayThisYear <= thirtyDaysFromNow;
    }

    return false;
});
```

I'm using my phone, so I haven't tested it. Make sure the logic is correct for your requirements before using it in a real application. I reccomend you use unit tests to ensure it functions correctly.

Comment: thanxs for Your reply and  Comment on @aquaraga Answer , so how can i Add Year that Linq Query

Comment: @SriramSatti, I've updated this answer to provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to give the condition:

```
DateTime.Parse(BdayItems.birthday) >= DateTime.Today
```

i.e:

```
jsonData.friends.data.Where(BdayItems => (BdayItems.birthday != null && 
DateTime.Parse(BdayItems.birthday) >= DateTime.Today &&
DateTime.Parse(BdayItems.birthday)<= DateTime.Today.AddDays(30))).OrderBy(BdayItems => BdayItems.birthday).ToList();
```

Comment: Hay thanks for Reply ... i get the Answer what I need .. But Now I observe that Small Mistake is Going there, I am Getting the List of Next 30 who enter there Birthdays in this("07/26") format only it's skipping if they Enter like this ("07/21/1989").

Comment: @SriramSatti, you shouldn't accept an answer unless it actually solves the problem. Read my answer for the solution to this problem in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that `DateTime` cannot account for an empty year. In case of not providing the year it assumes that it is the current one. That is:

```
 string stringDate = "05/01";
 int year = DateTime.Parse(stringDate).Year; // -> 2013
```

Also if the date is empty, it would account for a certain date anyway.

Thus the best thing you can do to deal with your problem is accounting for strings rather than for dates; and start considering dates once all the information is completed (day, month and year).

Additionally to this, your query does not deliver the kind of result you want (but other answers are taking care of this issue already).